# Interpreters for two polymorphic classes in one function

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, monads, typeclass, tagless-final

I have this polymorphic code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800042/two-polymorphic-classes-in-one-function)) with generic monads for model and client:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Writer

class Monad m => Model m where
  act :: Client c => String -> c a -> m a

class Monad c => Client c where
  addServer :: String -> c ()

scenario1 :: forall c m. (Client c, Model m) => m ()
scenario1 = do
  act "Alice" $ addServer @c "https://example.com"
```

and this is the pretty-print interpreter for the `Client` that explains the actions in the log via Writer monad:

```hs
type Printer = Writer [String]

instance Client Printer where
  addServer :: String -> Printer ()
  addServer srv = tell ["  add server " ++ srv ++ "to the client"]
```

Interpreter for the `Model` is difficult. I tried several things, each resulting in its own error:

1. "Couldn't match type ‘c’":

```
instance Model Printer where
  act :: String -> Printer a -> Printer a
  act name action = do
    tell [name ++ ":"]
    action
```

2. "`Cannot apply expression of type ‘Printer a’ to a visible type argument ‘(Printer a)’":

```
instance Model Printer where
  act :: forall a. String -> Printer a -> Printer a
  act name action = do
    tell [name ++ ":"]
    action @(Printer a)
```

3. "Couldn't match type ‘c’ with ‘WriterT [String] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’"

```hs
instance Model Printer where
  act :: Client c => String -> c a -> Printer a
  act name action = do
    tell [name ++ ":"]
    action
```

Somehow I need to tell that what was `c a` in `act` is now `Printer a`.

Maybe I need to have two parameters in the Model class - `m` for Model monad and `c` for Client monad, and Model class should also define the function `clientToModel :: c a -> m a`?

Is there a way to keep Model and Client decoupled? I probably would still need `clientToModel :: c a -> m a` for each pair?

I appreciate the advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type signature of `act` promises that it would work on *any* client, but here you're trying to constrain it to work only on the specific client called `Printer`. This violates the definition of the `Model` type class.

---

The usual pattern that you're apparently trying to follow is to define both `Model` and `Client` on the same monad, like this:

```
class Monad m => Model m where
  act :: String -> m a -> m a

class Monad m => Client m where
  addServer :: String -> m ()
```

This has the nice, easily understood semantics that both `act` and `addServer` are "ambient context" operations that are "available in the monad `m`". They're almost like "global functions", yet still mockable.

Then `Printer` could be one example of such monad, implementing both `Client` and `Model`. And then your production stack - like `ReaderT Config IO` or whatever you have - could be another example of such monad.

---

However, if you insist on `Model` and `Client` being defined on different monads, the only way to make the types work is to lift the `Client c` constraint from the signature of `act` to the signature of the `Model` class:

```
class (Monad m, Client c) => Model m c where
  act :: String -> c a -> m a
```

Which would have the meaning of "*every "model" monad works with a certain set of "client" monads, but not just any random "client" monad*".

Then you could define the `Printer` instance like this:

```
instance Model Printer Printer where
  act name action = do
    tell [name ++ ":"]
    action
```

And the types will work.

---

Having said that, I want to reiterate once again that your decision to define `Client` and `Model` on different monads is a smell to me. I strongly recommend that you reconsider your design as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanted to have different monads because of my original non-polymorphic code was written in `State r` monad with different record types for Model and Client to represent their state. Having 2 different monads for the sake of mocks makes everything look a bit uglier. Also Model has other methods without Client monad which means I will have to do TypeApplications again to tell compiler which Model type to use - and I can't figure out the syntax :) or to have both Client and Model in the same monad, as you suggested - the latter is probably better... Thank you again!